# gitignore [^.]* vs *

Tags: git, gitignore

In `.gitignore` inside a sub-directory I usually use `*` alone if I want everything in that sub-directory to be ignored. I recently read that I should use `[^.]*` for this purpose. Is there any difference between these two?

This is [the blog](http://blog.blenderbox.com/2014/04/16/gitignore-everything-inside-a-directory/) that I was reading.

Comment: I didn't think globs supported a *not*, so it would look like a regex, which I don't think is supported by `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not supported in `.gitignore`. If you want to negate a pattern, prepend it with a `!`.

Take a look at [the gitignore documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).